# UICollectionview scroll buttom to refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to load 5 articles coming from the server in to UICollection view cell 
When the user reaches the end of the collection fetch data from server and add to the already existing collection view , i am implementing this way but the old data is not displaying  new data is present in the collection view.

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y +                                                              scrollView.frame.size.height;
if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
    // we are at the end

    NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"REG_userId"];

    NSString *userToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"REG_TOKEN"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user_id" : userId ,

                                 @"token" : userToken ,

                                 @"pagination_type" : @"down" ,

                                 @"article_id" : articalID

                                 };
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://ec2-52-74-165-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/articles"
      parameters:parameters
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             // myArray = [responseObject objectForKey: @"result"];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {
                                [self.Collection reloadData];

                            });


         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];


}
```

}

I am getting the new Data and th old is not not displaying.

where to add the new data to old data so that all the articles can be seen.
Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Make your `myArray` into a `NSMutableArray`, don't forget to alloc init it on the `init` method of your viewController.

instead of

```
myArray = [responseObject objectForKey: @"result"];
```

you will do

```
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey: @"result"]];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I  don like this  myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  in viewDidLoad method, then while fetching data for next time when the user scroll to the bottom i am fetching the data and aded like this [myArray addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey: @"result"]]; error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: I didn't say to init in `viewDidLoad`, i said to init in the `- (instancetype)init` subclass method.

The error that you are getting is because you didn't do as i said (allot init the NSMutableArray) so the program things that it still is a NSArray, which is immutable and you cannot add objects to it.